# How to get background img to show up in :after selector?

Tags: html, css, background-image

So I love the **Corner Indicator** animation found here: http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLoadingEffects/

Currently there is a CSS animation playing inside of the :after selector.
I downloaded the file and tried to backwards engineer it below, basically instead of a CSS animation I want this animated gif to play inside of the corner triangle:

**My demo: http://leongaban.com/_stack/after/**

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/vzmPm/3/**

Note: the spinning image above the button is what I'm trying to get to show up inside of the corner triangle when you click the button.

Would you know how to get a background image to show up in an :after div?

[image]

```
/* Loading circle idea from http://codepen.io/Metty/details/lgJck */
.la-anim-10::before,
.la-anim-10::after {
    background-image: url('../img/loader-logo.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}

.la-anim-10::before {
    margin-left: -40px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-right-color: #bb344f;
    border-left-color: #bb344f;
    background-image: url('../img/loader-logo.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation: rotation 3s linear infinite;
    animation: rotation 3s linear infinite;
}

.la-anim-10::after {
    width: 77px;
    height: 77px;
    background-image: url('../img/loader-logo.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a demo fiddle?

Comment: You don't need the double colon for the pseudo-selectors. i.e. Not `::after`, but `:after`

Comment: @kunalbhat: You don't need it, but it's recommended.

Comment: Added it: http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/vzmPm/3/ :D

Comment: @BoltClock Whoa, that's news to me. Just out of curiosity, do you have a link for the recommendation?

Comment: @kunalbhat: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements These days it's only necessary to use single colons if you need to support older browsers like IE8.

Comment: @BoltClock, this is good to know: "This :: notation is introduced by the current document in order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements."

Comment: IE8 still has a big enough market share (around 5%ish I think) that I feel like the recommendation to use double colons `::` is a bit premature... especially since there is no harm in using a single, except for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you lose your image far away up the corner. It is caused by the rotation. In fact, this rotation also cause your animated image to be rotated.

Instead of rotated square arranged to look like a triangle, i simulate a triangle using borders. This way, no need to use rotation.

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 150px 150px 0;
border-color: transparent #f58733 transparent transparent;
```

I set up the image in the `:after` selector and adjusted your translation correctly for the triangle.

You now have a nice triangle having your animated image inside right in the corner without losing your animation effect.

Some adjustements still needed but i think this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzmPm/13/) will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the content property, something like:

```
#test:after {
    content: url('../img/loader-logo.gif');
}
```

Then you can remove the background image.

Comment: You won't be able to control the dimensions of the image though. It'll be rendered as is.

Comment: Hmm I tried that here: http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/vzmPm/5/ I can see it in the `#test` div, but still not in the corner triangle?

Comment: @Leon - There's a lot going on there with all the transforms and rotations. It is putting it in, but's it's probably rotated to a different corner than you expect.

Comment: Ah finally got it inside of the after here! http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/vzmPm/9/ However I lost the animation :( any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Something like <kbd>[this](http://jsfiddle.net/dmuVg/)</kbd>?

```
.la-anim-10::before {
    margin-left: -40px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    /*border-right-color: #bb344f;
    border-left-color: #bb344f;*/
    background: url('http://leongaban.com/_stack/after/img/loader-logo.gif') no-repeat center;
    border:none;
    -webkit-animation: rotation 3s linear infinite;
    animation: rotation 3s linear infinite;
```

}